# Are there any improvements of entities design if EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework-core, entity

I'm trying to create an ordering system. The base entity is `Sku` which represents some sku:

```
public class Sku
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    //a lot of Sku information here
}
```

Also I have `Customer` and `OrderPicker` entities

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // some Customer info here
    public List<Order>? Orders { get; set; }
}

public class OrderPicker
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    //some picker data here
    public List<Order>? Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Next, I want to create an entity which represents an order itself. It is obvious that an order has only one customer and customer has many orders. As far as I understand, this relationship can be modeled with the following code:

```
public class Order
{
      [Key]
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
      [Required]
      public Customer Customer { get; set; }
      public Guid CustomerGuid { get; set; }
      //order data
}
```

And in `AppContext`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .HasOne(o => o.Customer)
                .WithMany(c => c.Orders)
                .HasForeignKey(o => o.CustomerGuid)
                .HasPrincipalKey(c => c.Id);
```

Same applies to the order-orderpicker relation.

Problems show up when I try to model the order-sku relationship. Assume that order should contain many `Sku`s paired with their quantities in this order. I came up with an idea of introducing a connector entity `OrderItem`, which contains the following fields:

```
[Owned]
public class OrderItem
{
    public Guid SkuId { get; set; }
    public Sku Sku { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public uint Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Then in `Order` I can declare `ICollection<OrderItems>` and work with them:

```
public class Order
{
      [Key]
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
      [Required]
      public Customer Customer { get; set; }
      public Guid CustomerGuid { get; set; }
      public ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
      //order data
}
```

At this step I'm not sure how I can specify FK and PK for this entity and does it really need them.

Then I need to keep stock for skus. So I created an entity `StockItem`:

```
public class StockItem
{
    public Sku Sku { get; private set; }
    [Key]
    public Guid SkuId { get; private set; }
    [Required]
    public uint StockBalance { get; private set; }
}
```

The above does not work, different errors are thrown when I try to add initial migration. All the errors are about `StockItem` and its relationship with `Sku`. For example:

> The 'Sku' property 'StockItem.Sku' could not be mapped because the database provider does not support this type. Consider converting the property value to a type supported by the database using a value converter

So I have 2 questions:

- How can problems with both `OrderItem` and `StockItem` be solved?
- Is my entity design good enough and can it be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue may be using the SkuId for the PK of the StockItem. It sounds like the Sku is essentially like a Product? OrderItem can have it's own PK, like an OrderItemId referencing a Sku. If you want to track stock levels (balance) for Skus then you can create a separate table/entity for StockItem/StockLevel which can use an SkuId as a PK and FK to a Sku.

An outline to think about:

```
public class Order
{
      [Key]
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
      [Required]
      [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
      public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
      //order data

     public ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; private set; } = new List<OrderItem>();
}

public class OrderItem
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // order item details. such as Quantity.

    [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SkuId")]
    public virtual Sku Sku { get; set; }
}

public class Sku
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // SKU (product?) fields.
}

public class StockLevel
{
   [Key, ForeignKey(nameof(Sku))]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public uint StockBalance { get; set; }

   public virtual Sku Sku { get; set; }
}
```

When mapping out the relationships, one suggestion I have is to not declare FK properties, but rather to use shadow properties. This removes the issue of having to maintain two sources of truth which may differ at times, and lead to behaviour issues depending on which you use when a navigation property is loaded or not. The relationship between order and order item is one-to-many. One order has many order items. The reverse navigation property (OrderItem.Order) is optional, and if not needed I'd simply remove it and reference order items solely through the order Aggregate Root. The relationship between OrderItem and Sku is many-to-one. Many order items may refer to the same Sku. Order Item would have an Sku ID FK, Sku should generally not have an OrderItems collection. The relationship for Sku and StockLevel would be one-to-one where SKU is the primary in the relationship where one StockLevel can reference it sharing the same PK. Note that in the StockLevel, the Id column acts as both the PK and the FK to Sku.

The other suggestion when it comes to collections in entities is to always initialize these. Either in-line like the example above or in the constructor. With entities you want to avoid having any external code ever re-initialize a collection of related entities, so the Setter is made private. If any code were to set `order.OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();` this would quite easily lead to problems.

That should hopefully give you some ideas on setting up the relationships, but feel free to expand/comment on any specific questions or scenarios you still have issues with.

Comment: I have seen `virtual` keyword a lot [in docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) but it is not explained why we should mark properties `virtual`. So shall we? If we should then why?

Comment: Also I configured `OrderItem` as owned type because I don't need to have `DbSet<OrderItem>` in my `AppContext`. You removed this annotation. Can I keep it in place? And if I can, is it better to keep it or to remove it?

Comment: You mentioned that it is better to avoid any external value assignments with related entities. But what if the system is designed to allow such a behavior? Is it really a design issue or just a point to be aware of? For example, order has one customer which is already known when the order is initialized, but we don't know who will pick this order because it depends on which picker gets free first.

Comment: Only when it comes to re-initializing collections. If you have something like and it has a Picker reference, this would typically be a null-able reference that would be set at a later time, and possibly changed from one Picker/User to another. That is perfectly fine. It is only with collections where it may seem quicker/easier to change a collection by setting it to a new List containing a new set of items rather than removing and adding the changes individually. That is something to avoid so it's good to initialize collections once and make the setter private.

Comment: In some guides I have seen examples where in one-to-many relashionships authors specify `ICollection<EntityB>` in `EntityA` and specify only `EntityAId` in `EntityB` without specifying navigation property `public virtual EntityA` and without any annotations. Can such an approach be applied to my case? If the answer is yes then how EF understands that `EntityAId` is the relation key?

Comment: It can be done even without an EntityAId declared in EntityB via shadow properties. EF can manage FKs by convention so long as the FK name corresponds to the related Type. The relationship would be mapped explicitly in OnModelCreating or using an entity type configuration so for instance `modelBuilder.Entity<EntityA>().HasMany(x => x.EntityBs).WithOne();` should work if EntityB table has an EntityAId as the FK back. If you had a different FK name like "ParentId" then expand with: `.WithOne().ForeignKey("ParentId");`

Comment: Wow, this is super informative, thanks!